# NodeJs - TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null, but the app is working fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, null, try-catch

**UPDATE: I it checks for /:slug even if i go to a different route, i think thats causing the problem.**

I'm trying to create a URL Shortener with Nodejs, Expressjs, MongoDB and EJS.

Even though my application is working perfectly, I keep getting this error in terminal:
[image]

My routes :

```
const express = require("express");
const URLs = require("../models/urls");
const { findById, find } = require("../models/urls");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", { shortUrl: new URLs() });
});

router.post("/redirect", (req, res) => {
  let url = req.body.url;
  let slug = req.body.slug;
  let shortenUrl = new URLs({
    url: url,
    slug: slug,
  });
  shortenUrl.save();
  res.render("shortenUrl", { shortenUrl });
});

router.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.render("about");
});

router.get("/contact", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact");
});

router.get("/all", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var shortUrls = await URLs.find({});
    res.render("all", { shortUrls });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

//:TODO
router.get("/:slug", async (req, res) => {
  var shortUrl = await URLs.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).exec();
  try {
    console.log(shortUrl);
    var urls = await shortUrl.url;
    if (urls.includes("http", 0)) {
      return res.redirect(urls);
    } else {
      return res.redirect(`http://${urls}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I didn't get this error until I made API for the app (in separate routes file).
Also in my server I'm using:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

and using:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

doesn't help either.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you c:

Comment: What is `URLs` ? it's returning null

Comment: URLs is Mongoose Schema(model) and 
var shortUrl = await URLs.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug });

finds the url with slug and redirects the user to the url they stored before

Comment: what do you get when adding `console.log(shortUrl)` after the async call?

Comment: {
  url_id: 0,
  _id: 5f26fa4f84d13d77dadb94f4,
  url: 'numl.edu.pk',
  slug: 'numl',
  __v: 0
}

Comment: Well if it's working and you still get this message try to see if there's any other place that tries get a url (maybe a middleware that also runs this call, or maybe you have duplicate code you haven't removed from when refactoring code). it's hard to tell from the code you posted if it's working (and just outputing an error).

Comment: Try to use `return res.redirect(urls)` and `return res.redirect(`http://${urls}`);`

Comment: and also `const shortUrl = await ...` and `const urls = shortUrl.url`

Comment: From the mongoose docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne if you use async/await u have to use exec(). So try to change `await URLs.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug });` to `await URLs.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).exec();`

Comment: @Pukka I added returns, await and .exec(); but still having the same issue...I have updated the question with all routes. Even if I try to go to a different route, it still goes to /:slug

Comment: You dont have to await `await shortUrl.url`. I think youre Problem is that you hit the slug route on every request and the shortUrl can be null/undefined. Check it with `if(shortUrl )` before get the url property. If you accessing for example the /about route you get the about view?.

Comment: Checking it with if(shortUrl) did the trick! Thank you so much @Pukka! c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an if statement to the route and that solved the problem, thanks to @Pukka c:

```
router.get("/:slug", async (req, res) => {
  var shortUrl = await URLs.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).exec();
  if (shortUrl) {
    try {
      console.log(shortUrl);
      var urls = await shortUrl.url;
      if (urls.includes("http", 0)) {
        return res.redirect(urls);
      } else {
        return res.redirect(`http://${urls}`);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```